# build and deploy extjs application using cmd

Tags: extjs

I am new to extjs and CMD. We use java as backend and extjs as frontend. So what should be the deploy policy be. CMD also does a build and java people also do a build. Should we treat its as 2 builds ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually the back-end (java) and front-end (extjs) build would be separate, and these two deploy process should be independent. The package generated by sencha cmd does not include the server side.

For the full deploy you need to generate both java and extjs's package and upload to your server separately.